# why the line disappears after releasing the mouse cursor?

Tags: c++, qt

I paint over a QLabel that contains an image (QImage img) but after releasing the mouse cursor the drawing disappears.I think paintevent draws on label not on the image mPix how can I draw on the image? so that even if I remove the cursor the drawing remains

Thereafter I want to move these geometric shapes and resize them by the cursor if someone has an idea to help me.

`label.cpp`:

```
void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    mousePressed = true;
    switch (_paintMode) {  
        case PaintLine: {
            mLine.setP1(event->pos());
            mLine.setP2(event->pos());
        }
        break;
        case PaintCirc: {
            mCirc.setTopLeft(event->pos());
            mCirc.setBottomRight(event->pos());
        }
    }
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent* mouse_event) {
    if (mouse_event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
        switch (_paintMode) { 
            case PaintLine: {
                mLine.setP2(mouse_event->pos());
            }
            break;
            case PaintCirc:{
                mCirc.setBottomRight(mouse_event->pos());
            }
        }
        update();
    }
}

void Label::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen pen(Qt::red, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);

    painter.setPen(pen);
    if (mousePressed) {
        switch (_paintMode) {
            case PaintLine: {
                painter.drawLine(mLine);
            }
            break;
            case PaintCirc: {
                painter.drawEllipse(mCirc);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Label::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) {
    mousePressed = false;
}
```

`Mainwindow.cpp`:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered() {
    mPix=QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    ui->label->setPixmap(mPix);
}
```

Comment: Remove the condition `if(mousePressed)` in `paintEvent` to always draw the line.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what you said is like mousepressed == true in (mouseReleaseEvent) but that's not what I want. I want the line does not disappear once I release the cursor

Comment: no, what he meant was remove the `if(mousePressed)` from `paintEvent` so that the geometric figures are drawn even when the mouse is not pressed.

Comment: I already tested what he said, it gives me that the end point of a line is the starting point for another line but the old line disappears. u understand me...

Comment: I work with two classes one that contains the functions event (class label) and the other that contains the image (class mainwindow)

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Do you want to draw several lines?

Comment: no my problem is that the line drawn once I reach the end point it disappears I do not know if you understood me it's like I drew nothing ......

Comment: yes i want the new line to stay and then draw a new one the same thing for the circle draw several circle over the image

Comment: Try to think that when `paintEvent` is called, the previous drawn image is cleared. Now you should know why your line disappeared when you released your mouse (*see the comment by Romha Korev*). Now if you want to draw multiple lines, you can add a new line in a container (`QVector` for example) when a mouse button is pressed, and draw each line stored in the container in your `paintEvent`.

Comment: I do not know why the line disappears? ... I have already found in some examples that they use drawpixmap and their drawing remains on the image but it does not work for me. if you have an example for me to understand the source of the problem i have already tested to remove mousepressed in paintevent and to make mousepress = true in mousereleaseevent but it does not change anything

Comment: "and then draw a new one" won't work with only one member per type. add them to a list. always draw all items in the lists in paint event.

Comment: "Thereafter I want to move these geometric shapes" sounds like you should use a [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html)

Comment: can you illustrate this with an example..

Comment: I do not think that's the problem because I've already found an example that uses drawPixmap and it works for them the difference that they use a single class that contains a pixmap image with draw pixmap and I use two classes I  have already tested drawPixmap in paintevent but it does not work

Comment: draw pixmap won't help you if you want to change them. it's only a cache for updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that illustrates what we said.

- You do not need `mousePressed` in `paintEvent`
- Always draw everything.
- Use a list for several elements

It only draws ellipses for sake of brevity and simplicity.

```
#include <vector>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication> 
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget> 
#include <QtGui/QPainter> 
#include <QtGui/QMouseEvent> 

class Draw : public QWidget
{
public:
  Draw()
  : mMousePressed( false )
  , mCirc( nullptr ) {
  }

  void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event ) {
    mCircs.emplace_back();
    mCirc = &mCircs.back();
    mCirc->setTopLeft( event->pos() );
    mCirc->setBottomRight( event->pos() );
    mMousePressed = true;
  }

  void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* event ) {
    if( mMousePressed && mCirc) {
      mCirc->setBottomRight( event->pos() );
    }
    update();
  }

  void mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent* event ) {
    mMousePressed = false;
    mCirc = nullptr;
  }


  void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event ) {
    QWidget::paintEvent( event );
    QPainter painter( this );
    QPen pen( Qt::red, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin );

    painter.setPen( pen );
    for( auto const& circ : mCircs ) {
      painter.drawEllipse( circ );
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<QRectF> mCircs;
  QRectF* mCirc;
  bool mMousePressed;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Draw draw;
  draw.show();

  app.exec();
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tested the code in a new project and it works but when I integrate it in my old code I click on the button that paints the circle it shows me that the program has stopped working.

Comment: when I remove the pointer the code executes without this problem but it draws nothing

Comment: without seeing your changes I can't really help.

Comment: the problem might be that `mouseMoveEvent` runs across an initialized pointer. I"ll edit the example to make it safer.

Comment: without see your code I can't help. you"ll have to ask a new question.

Comment: I added the new code at the top and in this code I added your last modifications

Comment: don't do that.please undo your edits and ask a new question.

Comment: i've created a modified example that creates a Line on LeftButton and an Ellipse on Right button. you can find it [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fb01cb0bffd2036)