# Qt C++ QVector QLine QPoint drawingtool

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I have ***QVector m_vertices*** and ***QVector m_lines*** in my drawingWidget.h

I currently trying to do simple drawing tool, where i can manipulate with vertices and lines. I managed to draw multiple vertices on my "MainWindow", now i am trying to implement line between two vertices

The main idea is, that i have a pop-up menu, where i can choose a "tool". I can add vertex, remove vertex, move vertex, add line, delete line. The idea is , when i choose for example "Add Vertex" then the "m_state" will change to "Adding" so i can only add vertices. When i choose "Add Line" for example, then the "m_state" again will change, so that i can only choose two created vertices, that will result a line between them.

```
enum DrawingWidgetState {
    NO_TOOL_SELECTED,
    ADD_VERTEX_SELECTED,
    MOVE_VERTEX_SELECTED,
    DELETE_VERTEX_SELECTED,
    ADD_LINE_SELECTED,
    DELETE_LINE_SELECTED
};
```

Here, in the end, it turns out that if I click "Add Vertex" then when I put the second vertex, then it automatically puts a line between them

```
void DrawingWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(event->rect(), Qt::blue);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
    for(int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size() ; i++) {
        painter.drawEllipse(m_vertices[i], 20, 20);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size()-1 ; i++)
    {
        const QPoint& point1 = m_vertices[i];
        const QPoint& point2 = m_vertices[i+1];
        painter.drawLine(point1, point2);
    }
}
void DrawingWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if(m_state == ADD_VERTEX_SELECTED) {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            //m_x = event->x();
            //m_y = event->y();
            //update();
            QPoint point = event->pos();
            m_vertices.append(point);
            update();
        }
    }
    if(m_state == ADD_LINE_SELECTED) {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            for(int i = 0; i < m_vertices.size()-1 ; i++) {
                const auto &point1 = m_vertices[i];
                const auto &point2 = m_vertices[i+1];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me why this happens and what should i do to improve my code ? 
If something requires explanation, i will tell.

Comment: maybe this helps : [why the line disappears after releasing the mouse cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725290/why-the-line-disappears-after-releasing-the-mouse-cursor/56743845#56743845)